# can't assign random number to "setTimeout" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var randnum= Math.floor(Math.random() * (250 - 50) + 50) / 100;
        setTimeout(function() 
  {
    window.location.href = "http://{{current_site}}/mainpage"
  }, randnum);
    })
```

By the function above I'm trying to redirect to mainpage after a random amount of time. But `randnum` doesn't work and the function redirects immediately.

It works when I make a redirection by meta tag as below:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh">

var randnum= Math.floor(Math.random() * (250 - 50) + 50) / 100;
document.querySelector("meta[http-equiv='refresh']").setAttribute("content",randnum+",/anasayfa")
```

But redirection by meta tag's not working on every browser.

Comment: Your random number is way too small. The timeout of `window.setTimeout` is set in *ms*. You will not feel a difference between `1` and `1.2` *ms*. Specially since everything below `10` makes no difference. The value of the meta refresh is given in seconds, that is why it **works** there for you.

Comment: random number should be an integer greater than or equal to zero

Comment: @Lain that's correct thanks a lot fixed it. Ehsan Nazeri numbers work aswell.